# Which type of modulation is used in this RF Signal?

Tags: modulation, demodulation, software-defined-radio, reverse-engineering

I am working on reverse-engineering a few devices, I got some using ASK and FSK but I could not grasp this other one. I am attaching some photos from its captured signal took from URH (Universal Radio Hacker) and Inspectrum. Which type of modulation is this? and maybe some hints to how demodulate it.

**URH**
[image: from URH]

**Inspectrum**
[image: From Inspectrum]

I am also attaching some samples (433.92Mhz) in .Complex16s (URH default format)
[Drive folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Tp6SfCc5WXvGsvjeb4c3_cSnzOgOQJ2r?usp=sharing)

I tried to look for other types of modulation but I couldn't be certain of which one is and how I could demodulate to get bits out of it.

Comment: you'll have to tell us what these pictures show. Magnitude? Real part? imaginary part? phase? Over time? over frequency?

Comment: Hi @MarcusMüller I suppose the URH one is magnitude over time and Inspectrum is frequency over time centralized in 433.92MHz. It's the default view on each program, I also put the raw files in the Google Drive to a better look for anyone interested.

Comment: I must admit magnitude over time is really not that helpful, and it would also really look more like real or imaginary part; can you *verify* what you say? I'm sure that's documented somehow.

Comment: Sure, I will check. Do you use some software to analyze rf signal? Because I can try to put the raw files there and update the question with images that are more 'reliable' for you.

Comment: The one used in Inspectrum is a spectrogram derived from fft, so a frequency over time (vertical axis - frequency (central 433.92MHz), horizontal axis - time)

Comment: top graph looks like some type of frequency modulation is used, maybe frequency modulation of an analog signal. Bottom graph also looks like some type of frequency modulation is used